# How to print datagridview having 100s of rows

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to print a datagrid which having 7 columns and 100s of rows. For dat i used bitmap. But it only prints upto 55 rows i.e. Only 1 page print page, it not generate the multiple pages for printing. Sorry for my bad english. Please help.

Thanx in advance..

Here is my code:

```
Private bitmap As Bitmap
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    '************************RESIZE DATAGRID VIEW TO FULL SIZE **********************
    Dim height As Integer = DataGridView1.Height
    DataGridView1.Height = (DataGridView1.RowCount + 1) * DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height

    '************************CREATE A BITMAP AND DRAW THE DATAGRID VIEW ON IT **********************************
    bitmap = New Bitmap(Me.DataGridView1.Width, Me.DataGridView1.Height)
    DataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.DataGridView1.Width, Me.DataGridView1.Height))

    '************************Resize datagrid view back to original size ********************************************
    DataGridView1.Height = height

    '********************* show the print preview ***********************************************************
    PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1

    PrintPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1

    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Private Sub PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    '********************************************* PRINT THE CONTENTS ************************************************************
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Here's an example. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VBNet-Printing-Example-bc3b0176

Comment: You'd have a look at [Another DataGridView Printer](http://web4.codeproject.com/Articles/18042/Another-DataGridView-Printer?msg=3131642) for a try in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

> PrintPageEventArgs

has a property called

> HasMorePages

. You would need to subtract the page height from the datagridview height and determine if there is a need to print another page. It yes, then you can set it to true and it will re run the sub again.

```
Private Sub PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    '********************************************* PRINT THE CONTENTS ************************************************************
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0)

    Dim rectPrint As RectangleF = ev.PageSettings.PrintableArea
    ' changed this to width if printing in landscape mode
    If Me.DataGridView1.Height - rectPrint.Height > 0 Then e.HasMorePages = True

End Sub
```